# SQL query to count number of categories a contact belongs to

Tags: mysql, sql

It's been a long week and my brain's frazzled.

I have a database with three tables:

- `contacts`
- `contacts_categories`
- `contacts_categories_join`

There are various categories, and contacts can belong to a category, many categories, or none. The structure of `contacts_categories_join` is:

```
id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
contact_id INT UNSIGNED
category_id INT
```

Pretty simple.

What I'm after is a way to count the number of categories a contact belongs to, given the ID.

**EDIT:** I kind of got there with a `GROUP BY` statement using a `COUNT` on the `category_id` column, but unfortunately this doesn't return the IDs of contacts assigned to zero categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM contacts_categories_join
 WHERE contact_id = ID
```

Where `ID` is the given id.

If you asked about all contacts (but it is not obvious from your question), then:

```
   SELECT c.id,
          COUNT(j.contact_id)
     FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN contacts_categories_join j ON j.contact_id = c.id
 GROUP BY c.id
```

(Supposing your `contact` table has `id` field)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was wanting the count of all contacts. But this query does what I need, so thanks!